# Two lists - find all permutations - even multiple to one

Tags: python, permutation

I have two lists and I need to find all permutations.

The kicker is that multiple "number" items (as per example below) can be assigned. No assignments are also allowed.

So this:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]
```

Would become this (the list order doesn't matter, so `[1, 2] = [2, 1]`:

```
[
    "not only this"
    {'a': [1], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [1]},
    "but also"
    {'a': [1], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]},

]
```

Or for example this:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
```

Would go something along the lines of:

```
[
    {'a': [], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [1], 'b': [3]},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [3]},
    {'a': [3], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [3], 'b': [2]},
    "but also"
    {'a': [], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1, 2, 3]},
    {'a': [1], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3]},
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]},
    {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [1, 3]},
    {'a': [2, 3], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [1]},
    "etc..."
]
```

---

Created [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709116/two-lists-find-all-permutations-even-multiple-to-one-round-2) for when the list order does matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
import itertools

def f(p, names, numbers):
    r = {name : [] for name in names}
    for i, j in enumerate(p):
        if j >= 0:
            r[names[j]].append(numbers[i])

    return r

def get_vals(names, numbers):
    p_iter = itertools.product(range(-1, len(names)), repeat=len(numbers))

    return [f(p, names, numbers) for p in p_iter]
```

You can call `get_vals` to return the desired list.  Here's the small example:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]

r = get_vals(names, numbers)

for d in r:
    print(d)
```

This prints:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Here's the larger example:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

r = get_vals(names, numbers)

for d in r:
    print(d)
```

This prints:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': []}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! Have to look into itertools to see what going on here, but it indeed does what I need.

Comment: I said that the list order doesn't matter, so `[1, 2] = [2, 1]`. Only now I realize the order does in fact matter. I suspect that `itertools.permutations()` will be used but can't seem to figure it out. Is that an easy fix or should I create a separate question?

Comment: @Seminko At this point it might be easiest to post a new question.  Make sure you describe exactly what the desired order should be.  In the solution I posted, the individual sub-list entries are ordered, but the top-level list of all the dictionaries may not be in the order you want.

Comment: created here, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709116/two-lists-find-all-permutations-even-multiple-to-one-round-2

Answer (score 2):

A better answer was already posted, but this was a good exercise for using `itertools` and this also works:

```py
from itertools import combinations, product

names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

perm_list = [list(perm) for perm_len in range(len(numbers)+1) for perm in combinations(numbers, perm_len)]   # generate permutations

perm_dict = [{names[0]: perm1, names[1]: perm2} for perm1, perm2 in product(perm_list, perm_list) if not set(perm1) & set(perm2)]   # get all possible non-overlapping combinations

for perm_combination in perm_dict:
    print(perm_combination)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [3], 'b': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': []}
```

**Edit:** an even less pretty, but functional version that allows for an arbitrary number of names:

```py
from itertools import combinations, product

names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

perm_list = [list(perm) for perm_len in range(len(numbers)+1) for perm in combinations(numbers, perm_len)]   # generate permutations

name_perm_list = [perm_list for _ in names]

perm_dict = [{names[i]: perms[i] for i in range(len(names))} for perms in product(*name_perm_list) if len(set().union(*perms)) == sum([len(set(perm)) for perm in perms])]   # get all possible non-overlapping combinations

for perm_combination in perm_dict:
    print(perm_combination)
```

Output:

```py
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [1, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [2, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [1], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1], 'c': [2, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [2], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2], 'c': [1, 3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [3], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [3], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [3], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [3], 'c': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 3], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 3], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [], 'c': [2, 3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [3], 'c': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [3], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [], 'c': [1, 3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1], 'c': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [3], 'c': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [3], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1, 3], 'c': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': [], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [], 'c': [1, 2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1], 'c': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [2], 'c': []}
{'a': [3], 'b': [2], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [], 'c': [3]}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': []}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [], 'c': [2]}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2], 'c': []}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [], 'c': []}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [], 'c': [1]}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [1], 'c': []}
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [], 'c': []}
```

The overlap check is pretty ugly because I couldn't think of a better way to get the overlap of multiple sets since intersection won't cut it.

Comment: I said that the list order doesn't matter, so `[1, 2] = [2, 1]`. Only now I realize the order does in fact matter. I suspect that `itertools.permutations()` will be used but can't seem to figure it out. Is that an easy fix or should I create a separate question?

Comment: @Seminko The fix is extremely simple! Just replace `combinations` from the import and `perm_list` comprehension to `permutations` :)

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Without itertools... for each number, append it to either name's list:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

ds = [{name: [] for name in names}]
for number in numbers:
    ds += [
        {k: v[:] + [number] * (k == name)
         for k, v in d.items()}
        for d in ds
        for name in names
    ]

for d in ds:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [3], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2, 3]}
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1, 3]}
{'a': [3], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```