# Two lists - find all permutations - even multiple to one - Round 2

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

[I asked this question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629666/two-lists-find-all-permutations-even-multiple-to-one/), but things changed so new question is in order.

---

I have two lists and I need to find all permutations.

The kicker is that multiple "number" items (as per example below) can be assigned. No assignments are also allowed.

So this:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]
```

Would become this:

```
[
    "not only this"
    {'a': [1], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [2], 'b': [1]},
    "but also"
    {'a': [], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': []},
    {'a': [2, 1], 'b': []},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [2]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]},
    {'a': [], 'b': [2, 1]},
]
```

The difference to my previous question is that in this case the list order DOES in face matter, so `[1, 2] != [2, 1]` - both cases need to be encompassed.

---

Also, the lists above are only for illustration purposes, since in the real scenario I will be using classes:

```
class sample_class():
    def __init__(self, parameter_1, parameter_2):
        self.parameter_1 = parameter_1
        self.parameter_2 = parameter_2
        
first_group_example_list = [sample_class(x, x+1) for x in range(2)]
second_group_example_list = [sample_class(x+5, x+5+1) for x in range(2)]
```

---

Now, since the number of permutations gets very high very quickly, speed is king. Not sure if using classes compared to list of ints has any effect on speed, but I suspect so, so if there are any good practices when it comes to that, please let me know.

Not sure if it has any effect on speed / memory, but since the lists are ordered, I was thinking about using element indexes when generating the permutations, instead of the classes themselves, and pull the actual class instances only in the subsequent processing steps.

---

EDIT: Let's not complicate things with the classes and stick with names and numbers (as long the solution doesn't care what type the two input lists are (either ints or strings)). I will figure out the rest, *hopefully*, as I go.

---

EDIT2: [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bn%21%2C%5C%2840%29k-1%5C%2841%29%21%5D%20%E2%80%A2%20sum%5C%2840%29j%3D0%20to%20n%5C%2841%29%20of%20Divide%5B%5C%2840%29j%2Bk-1%5C%2841%29%21%2C%5C%2891%29j%21%5C%2840%29n-j%5C%2841%29%21%5C%2893%29%5D%5C%2844%29%20n%3D3%5C%2844%29%20k%3D4) is the solution that will calculate the number of "permutations".

```
import math

numbers = 6 # length of numbers list
names = 7 # length of names list

result = 0
for j in range(numbers + 1):
    result += math.factorial(j + names - 1) / (math.factorial(j) * math.factorial(numbers - j))

result *= math.factorial(numbers) / math.factorial(names - 1)

print(result) # number of "permutations"
```

Comment: To be clear, you don't care about the order of the dicts in the top-level list right?  You just want all the permutations in the dict value lists?  Also, `{'a': [], 'b': []}` is missing from the example, but I assume you still want that?

Comment: Missing permutation added. And no, I don't care about the order in the top-level list, if by top-level list you mean the example list mentioned after "Would become this" in my question. Also I mentioned I will be using classes, since when I was trying to input dicts instead of strings / ints in your previous solution, it didn't work, hence I ended up using list indexes. Thx

Comment: It's not clear how you intend to use the classes.  Are they meant to replace the lists-of-int?  If so, the sample class shown won't work since it's hard-wired to exactly two values.  How do you want to represent `[]`, or `[5]`, or `[7,3,9]` in your class?

Comment: @Tom Karzes - updated the question - let's stick with names and numbers.

Comment: Can there be duplicate names or duplicate numbers?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy - no, unique only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fast solution.  Note that it doesn't do any searching - it simply rolls the solutions out:

```
import itertools

def perm_lists(d, names, ix):
    if ix == len(names):
        yield d.copy()
        return

    name = names[ix]
    for m in itertools.permutations(d[name]):
        d[name] = m
        yield from perm_lists(d, names, ix+1)

def f(p, names, numbers):
    d = {name : [] for name in names}
    for i, j in enumerate(p):
        if j >= 0:
            d[names[j]].append(numbers[i])

    yield from perm_lists(d, names, 0)

def val_gen(names, numbers):
    p_iter = itertools.product(range(-1, len(names)), repeat=len(numbers))

    for p in p_iter:
        yield from f(p, names, numbers)
```

This implements a generator, so you don't have to pay the cost of the entire top-level list if all you want to do is iterate over the values, but you can of course convert it to a list if desired.

Also note that this uses tuples in place of the value lists.  These are more memory-efficient than lists, and fall out naturally from the implementation, but it's trivial to convert them to lists if needed.

Here's an example:

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]

for d in val_gen(names, numbers):
    print(d)
```

This produces:

```
{'a': (), 'b': ()}
{'a': (2,), 'b': ()}
{'a': (), 'b': (2,)}
{'a': (1,), 'b': ()}
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': ()}
{'a': (2, 1), 'b': ()}
{'a': (1,), 'b': (2,)}
{'a': (), 'b': (1,)}
{'a': (2,), 'b': (1,)}
{'a': (), 'b': (1, 2)}
{'a': (), 'b': (2, 1)}
```

If you want the value lists to be lists rather than tuples, just change:

```
d[name] = m
```

to:

```
d[name] = list(m)
```

in `perm_lists`.  This will produce:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [2], 'b': []}
{'a': [], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': []}
{'a': [2, 1], 'b': []}
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [2], 'b': [1]}
{'a': [], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': [], 'b': [2, 1]}
```

If you want to create the full top-level list, rather than using the generator to iterate over it, you can use:

```
full_list = list(val_gen(names, numbers))
```

I suggest doing some timing experiments.  I believe this will be fast when used on large amounts of data.

Comment: Awesome solution! Tuples are absolutely fine. I will definitely look into generators. Again, kudos, Mr. Tom!

Comment: @Seminko Glad I could help.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: *"fast when used on large amounts of data"* - So you have a suggestion how large I shall use in benchmarking? @Seminko How large are your actual lists??

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm just pointing out that the growth function for the performance should be well-behaved.  I.e., it avoids searching and backtracking and other things that would tend to be problematic on large data sets, which is presumably what OP is dealing with since speed was stated as a critical factor.

Comment: Ugh, came across wrong. Stupid phone changed my "Do" to "So" again. Just wondering whether you have a suggestion, as I'd like to try this myself and benchmark, and don't want to do something unfair. I'm thinking of making both lists equally large, and as large as possible so that the benchmark runs in a few seconds. Unless OP says something different.  Sounds good?

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure, go for it :)  You could try a few tests, some with one somewhat small and the other huge (in either order), and another with the lists balanced in size.  I haven't tried it on large lists, so it should be interesting to see how it does.  You could compare the time it takes to the length of the resulting generator output.

Comment: @KellyBundy - I need to figure out how large the two lists can be. My time budget for one calculation is about 15 seconds, so however many elements that is. Shame I suck at math. Time to ask reddit :)

Comment: @TomKarzes updated the first post with the calculation of the number of "permutations".